# XCode 6 Unit Testing Without Building

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode6

Is there a way to prevent the app from building when I am just unit testing? When I run the test it builds the app and that takes minutes. I have written the tests in Swift and targets ios 8.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 8+, you can pass the "test-without-building" option.

```
$ xcodebuild -workspace <your_xcworkspace> -scheme <your_scheme> -sdk iphonesimulator -destination ‘platform=iOS Simulator,name=<your_simulator>,OS=10.2’ test-without-building
```

Read more here: https://medium.com/xcblog/speed-up-ios-ci-using-test-without-building-xctestrun-and-fastlane-a982b0060676